# How to access to my Grid in Dynamic CRM365 View

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am working on Dynamic CRM365 plugin, in my entity view, I need to know which item has been selected, before I use **DOM** to detect, however, I can't pass the certification, because all **DOM** access are risk and need to be replaced, therefore, I checked **Xrm.Page.getControl** and **Xrm.Page.ui.controls**, but no luck.

[image]

I passed **Xrm.Page.getControl("ssl_notesforsigns")** or **Xrm.Page.getControl("ssl_notesforsign")** => return null

I call **Xrm.Page.ui**, **ui** = null.

Any idea how to get grid by code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is good to hear that you no longer want to access the DOM. As you say, that is entirely unsupported.

What is the name of the subgrid on your form? If you go to a form editor and look at the properties for the subgrid, you will see the name (I am guessing that it is not called *ssl_notesforsigns*). This name is the one you should use, and it can be used when calling `Xrm.Page.getControl("namehere")` to get your grid context.

`Xrm.Page` has been deprecated (even though you can still use it). Instead, you should get a reference to your grid context through the execution context. See [Client API grid context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/clientapi-grid-context). For code executing on a form event, you can get your grid context through the form context as follows:

```js
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); // get the form Context
var gridContext = formContext.getControl("namehere"); // get the grid context
```

When you have a reference to your grid context, you can get the selected rows using [getSelectedRows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/grids/grid/getselectedrows):

```js
var allSelectedRows = gridContext.getGrid().getSelectedRows();
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik, hovever, I am using grid in View, not subgrid in form, it seems I can't use Xrm.Page in View, I don't want use form, since my task suppose to be simple to just let user to pick some items. Any idea to get access in Grid of View?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. How does your current JavaScript get called? Would it be possible for you to create a ribbon button to trigger your functionality, and then use [SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/129783-pass-the-currently-selected-grid-row-s-to-a-custo)?

Comment: Thanks Henrik, it seems it still need a form, I think I need to build a HTML web resource, then I can use webapi to read/build/operate my own Grid.